# Error in DRAW GUI event on android. (GameMaker)

Tags: gui, game-maker

Image of the game on a mobile phone:

[image]

As you can see the **maze** (draw event) has been resized correctly.

But the **yellow post-it** (draw GUI event) has not been scaled or displayed in the correct location (center of the screen). Same thing with **GUI layout** (draw GUI event).

Because this is a small stage/room (size) I do not use the artifice of views, I thought that could be because of that the problem, but I enabled the views and did not get any different result.

[image]

Picture of the game on a computer (like it should be on the phone):

[image]

OBS - One information that can help you to help me solve the problem, is that to draw the post- it I use the following code: **draw GUI event** `draw_sprite(spr_Post,0,640,360);`.

**640** is the half screen width of the game and also the room, **360** is half the height of the game screen and also the room.

It seems that somehow the room on the cell phone is different size than 1280x720.

I do not put the following code: **draw GUI event** `draw_sprite(spr_Post,0,room_width/2,room_height/2)`, because there are much larger phases that need views, so the post-it needs to be in the **center of the screen of the player**, and with this code it ends up being in the center of the phase.

I tested the game on Bluestacks and it did not happen the same as on the phone.

Comment: This sounds like a game maker bug. I would send an email to yoyogames asking for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was this:

(Draw GUI Event)

```js
display_set_gui_size(1280,720);
draw_sprite(spr_Post,0,640,360);
```

Reference:

https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/windows%20and%20views/display_set_gui_size.html

Answer (score 0):

Here I am again to the rescue XD

Instead of using room_width or room_height that are the size of the room, use the size of the view, the variables are view_xview, view_yview, view_wview and view_hview that are related to the current view so use the index [0] with the number of the view on all variables.

`draw_sprite(sprite_index, view_xview[0]+view_wview[0]/2, view_yview[0]+view_hview[0]/2);`

It will make the object origin to be in the center of the screen/view.

Edit: The Draw_GUI event is relative to the view coordinate system.
Edit2: added some code to try

Check them in the manual to see examples.

Comment: I changed the code to `draw_sprite(spr_Post,0,view_wview[view_object]/2,view_hview[view_object]/2);` and did not change the result.

Comment: Before I tried with the number of the vision, but also with no result.

Comment: I've added some code, it is typically used to fix healthbars to the view

Comment: For me it worked as follows: `display_set_gui_size(1280,720);`. In the next line just put: `draw_sprite(spr_Post,0,640,360);`

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso If that worked for you, please consider sharing it as an answer that you can mark Accepted.